# how can I simplify code that maintains state?

Tags: haskell

I have code below that traverses a graph, and it maintains a map that represents this graph, so it has to return this map as part of the function value.

I am a novice in haskell and I do not know if I can use a monad of some sort that would allow me to hide these details and avoid returning state explicitly. And if I can use a monad then I do not know which and how. Please help.

```
expand k m =
    case Map.lookup k m of
      Just (Complete x) -> (x, m)
      Just (Initial x)  -> let m0 = Map.adjust (const $ Visited x) k m
                               (x', m1) = traverse x m0
                               m2 = Map.adjust (const $ Complete x') k m1
                           in (x', m2)
      Just (Visited _)  -> error ("circular reference: " ++ k)
      Nothing           -> error ("name not found: " ++ k)
    where
      traverse (Name k) m = expand k m
      traverse (Or x y) m = let (x', m0) = traverse x m
                                (y', m1) = traverse y m0
                            in (Or x' y', m1)
      traverse (Not x) m  = let (x', m') = traverse x m
                            in  (Not x', m')
```

Comment: if I get you right you are interested in finding out for yourself right? In this case: the **monad you are searching** is named `State` - on [haskelWiki](https://wiki.haskell.org/State_Monad) is a nice overview and of course you don't have to implement it yourself - you can use [`State` from the mtl package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-State-Strict.html#t:State)

Comment: yes, I want to find out for myself, thanks!